# connecting to azure service bus queue from ssis

Tags: azure, ssis

I have a requirement where I need to put a ticket into an azure queue from a SSIS package.

I have previously set up control flows using "Message Queue Tasks" for add a ticket in MSMQ but did not know if there was way to trigger tickets into an azure service bus queue.

What I have tried:

As a alternative solution, I am accessing use a REST web service as a middle man. I trigger the webservice using "Web Service Task" which then puts a ticket in the azure queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches of solving the problem in general

### approach 01 : chicken out.

you could technically have a separate infrastructure piece between your SSIS package and the azure service bus queue which could reference the Azure SDK using nuget and put tickets for you, your SSIS package would then be calling this REST web api to put the ticket in.

### approach 02 A : script task with .dll reference

You could reference the Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll inside a script task in the SSIS package which will construct  a BrokeredMessage and put it in the queue.

The dll needs to be added to the GAC using gacutil.exe for the script task to work at runtime.

### approach 02 B : script task calling azure service bus REST API

You could create a script task which calls and puts message using azure service bus REST API. There is a tutorial available here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh416754.aspx but I never happened get beyond the point of sending actual data.